# LA FECHA EN PHP SE COLOCA MAL, SE COLOCA UN DÍA DESPUES

Tags: php, date, fpdf

Estoy realizando un programa en PHP para realizar certificados mediante la librería FPDF, el problema que me surge es que utilizo es la función date() para colocar mi fecha actual, sin embargo el día me sale como unas 12 horas adelantado aproximadamente, me gustaría saber como se podría resolver este problema, o si puedo poner la fecha obtenida de la computadora ya que no solo se realiza en México la certificación y siento que no seria optimo obtenerla por la región, realmente recién empece con PHP y desconozco, también quisiera saber si se puede poner el mes en español. Intente colocar : `setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES.UTF-8");` sin embargo no me funciono...

```
//setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES.UTF-8");
$fecha = "Ciudad de México a " . date("j"). " de " . date("M") . " del " . date("Y");

$pdf=new FPDF('L','mm','A4');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('img/constancia.png',0,0,297,210,'PNG');

//FECHA
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Text(15,195,utf8_decode($fecha));

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero no es lo más conveniente, ya que si ingresan de otro lado no tendran la fecha de su certificado

Comment: Tendrías que obtener la fecha/hora del cliente (vía JavaScript) y mandarla al servidor (PHP), usando Ajax. Esa es la única forma de garantizar que cada PDF será generado con la fecha/hora de cada persona, independientemente de si se conecta desde México, desde Japón o desde Australia, o cualquier país. PHP te da la hora del servidor y si quieres otra hora tendrías que conocer previamente la zona horaria desde la cual se conecta cada persona, pero esa información está en el cliente, no en el servidor.